# How do I call SetHITTypeNotification in Amazon Mechanical Turk (MTurk) using RTurk?

Tags: mechanicalturk

I'm trying to make this kind of request:

```
https://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/?Service=AWSMechanicalTurkRequester
&AWSAccessKeyId=[the Requester's Access Key ID]
&Operation=SetHITTypeNotification
&Signature=[signature for this request]
&Timestamp=[your system's local time]
&HITTypeId=T100CN9P324W00EXAMPLE
&Notification.1.Destination=janedoe@example.com
&Notification.1.Transport=Email
&Notification.1.Version=2006-05-05
&Notification.1.EventType=AssignmentSubmitted
```

based on the documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_SetHITTypeNotificationOperation.html

Here's my code:

```
RTurk.SetHITTypeNotification(:hit_type_id => "3M36IJVRR974ABAC76WQ0TCVKX9SIA", :notification => { :destination => "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/971351813114/MechanicalTurk", :transport => "SQS", :version => "2006-05-05", :event_type => "assignment_accepted" }, :active => true)
```

and here's the error that I'm seeing:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_param_hash' for #<Hash:0x007ffe1ed82858>
```

Anyone know what the to_param_hash error means or how to address it?

Answer (score 1):

Spent a couple hours on this problem. Answering here in case it helps others with the same situation. It turns out that I need to create a Notification object, which makes a lot of sense when you look at how to work with Notifications in RTurk in other contexts. Here's a snippet that works:

```
n = RTurk::Notification.new("https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/971351813114/MechanicalTurk", "SQS", "2006-05-05", "AssignmentAccepted")
a = RTurk.SetHITTypeNotification(:hit_type_id => "3M36IJVRR974ABAC76WQ0TCVKX9SIA", :notification => n, :active => true)
t = RTurk.SendTestEventNotification(:notification => n, :test_event_type => "AssignmentAccepted")
```

Hope this helps others in the same situation!